# ASP.net image editor with layering

Tags: asp.net, image-editor

I need an image editor which I can add to my ASP.net project, as an image editor for DMS, so user can open the selected image with the desired editor and then he can edit and add new layer (i.e. his signature).

I need something just like this http://pixlr.com/ but the problem with the latter is being online only !!

Answer (score 0):

Pixlr now provides the [API](http://pixlr.com/developer/api/) to work with which you can use in your site.

There are also [a few tutorials](https://sites.google.com/site/pixlrgrabber/pixlr-tutorials) hosted on youtube you can look into.